# How can I offer both URL-based and COOKIE-based SESSION TRACKING depending on Cookie Support?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies, cookieless

I have a PHP site where 20% of visitors do not have cookie support.

How can I offer both URL-based and Cookie-based Session Tracking depending on Cookie Support?

In other words, if the user accepts cookies, then we use cookie-based Session Tracking.  But if they do not, then we switch to URL-based Session Tracking so that those users can still utilize the site.

I do not want to lose 20% of my users and I do not want a site that is 100% based on URL Session Tracking as that not only poses a security risk but also certain limitations that I don't want the other 80% of users to have to endure.

Comment: You nullify the security risk argument, a malicious user could just disable cookies himself.

Comment: @TJHeuvel:  I'm referring specifically to the security risk of a malicious user hijacking another user's Session or having a legitimate user inadvertently send their Session URL via e-mail/IM to a friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP pretty much does the job for you automatically. It will append the session ID to all links if no cookie can be used. This should work out-of-the box with any default PHP installation.

Comment: This has not been my experience at all, perhaps due to specific settings on the site I inherited.  In fact, it would seem for this to be the case, the default value for session.use_trans_sid would have to be true, but it is actually false.  Can you please link to where it says this is the default behavior?

Comment: Oh. You are right. My fault. [Over here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid) it says that the default is 0. I'm fairly sure that all of my PHP installations used it. I'm confused now.

Comment: What about trying to set a cookie on the homepage, and then checking to see if the cookie was set correctly on the second page, and if not, then setting session.use_trans_sid = 1 so it appends the SID to the URL automatically?  Would something like that work?  If so, could you please edit your solution to incorporate something like this so I can accept it?  Thanks.

Comment: I could, but I'd have to delve into the PHP documentation. And you can do that yourself just as well. ;) I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help. Maybe someone else will have an answer for you.